# System Date as a Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm using Oracle Business Intelligence, and creating a custom report.  I've been able to create and have everything work except there's an issue in using parameters on scheduled reports.

This is forcing me to hard code the auto-updating dates in the Data model.  Is anyone able to assist with the best way to replace my parameters below?

Essentially, I'm looking for `START_DATE_PARAMETER` to be replaced with the System Date **MINUS 15**, and `END_DATE_PARAMETER` to be replaces with System Date **PLUS 1**.

```
AND table1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE >= :START_DATE_PARAMETER
AND table1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE <= :END_DATE_PARAMETER
AND table2.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE >= :START_DATE_PARAMETER
AND table2.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE <= :END_DATE_PARAMETER
```

Comment: Have you tried `(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 15)` and `(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1)`? I assume you mean 15 and 1 days, not months or years or hours or anything.

Comment: @jpmc - why CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and not SYSDATE? And why offer it as a comment, when obviously it is an answer?

Comment: @mathguy `SYSDATE` includes a timestamp anyway, so I prefer the more explicitly named `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` also includes a time zone. As for why a comment, because if that's the answer, this is a poorly researched question and deserves to be closed instead of answered.

Comment: @jpmc26 - SYSDATE and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP are different data types (and no, SYSDATE does NOT include a "timestamp" - although perhaps you didn't mean that, you meant it includes "time of day" which is correct). From everything the OP said, it seems the data type used there is date, not timestamp. Am I missing something? (And yes, it does matter - if you use a timestamp, you force Oracle to make an implicit conversion).

Comment: @mathguy Good. Maybe the OP will learn about time zones and properly handle them instead of using outdated data types that don't include them. I really don't feel like having an argument about minutia. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone's feedback.  I am fairly new to SQL, and am trying to develop my skills so all of the input is much appreciated.

Because my parameters are meant to include more than I'll actually need, I can potentially use either the 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' or 'SYSDATE' solution.  The one piece of the puzzle that I was missing was the inclusion of 'TRUNC('

AND table1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE >= (TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 15)

AND table1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE <= (TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1)

AND table2.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE >= (TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 15)

AND table2.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE <= (TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1)